# Updating an instance registered with Unity container

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am using Unity for dependency injection and have the instance of a class Config that implements IConfig registered with the Unity Container.

```
IConfiguration config = new Configuration();

unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(config);
```

When the app is running and the user loads a saved configuration, I would like to update the instance stored in Unity with the configuration object loaded. E.g. something like the psuedo code below

```
IConfiguration loadedConfig = FileLoadService.Load(filepath);
unityContainer.Instance = loadedConfig;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just re-register the instance by calling

```
unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(config);
```

But a better solution would be to change your `FileLoadServce.Load(filepath)` logic so that it updates the values of your existing configuration object. The benefit of this solution would be that already resolved references (by calling `unityContainer.Resolve<IConfiguration>()`) to this config object are updated, too.

Comment: as is often the way I found the answer shortly after posting. Thanks for the tip with regard to updating the resolved references though.

Comment: @Peter- hi, regarding your comment with the resolve references , if I have a class that use Resolve, and I override the first instance as your example. does it mean that from now and ever each time i'll use the class the resolve will point to the old instance? or is it being resolved at runtime? Thank You